# How do I Fix My Nested If Statements to show all the desired output, and not just a select few?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating a report whereby I'd like to filter the records, by whether they are expired, expiring in a year or they have started their retention period or just valid data using a single column.

Below is my calculated column to help me achieve that.

The problem, however, is that the "Records on retention period" is not showing on its own, but when I choose the rest of the options I can see it's value in the displayed results.

How do I check that first the record is not expired before checking if it has started the retention period.

I've tried rearranging the ifs but the results are not okay when I tamper.

here is my formula

```
Record Status = 
IF(
Records[Destruction Date]<>BLANK() && Records[Destruction Date] <= Today() , 
"Expired Records" , 
IF(
Records[Destruction Date]<>BLANK() && YEAR(Records[Destruction Date]) >= YEAR(Today())+1 , 
"Records Expiring In An Year", 
IF(
Records[Retention Begins]<>BLANK() &&  Records[Retention Begins]<=TODAY() , 
"Records on Retention Period", 
"Valid Records"
)))
```

I expect to get: Expired Records, Records Expiring In An Year, "Records on Retention Period", or "Valid Records".

To enable one to filter during visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I could find logical errors in the calculation of `Records Expiring In An Year` & `Records on Retention Period`, see if the following formula works,

```
Record Status = 
IF(
Records[Destruction Date]<>BLANK() && Records[Destruction Date] <= Today() , 
"Expired Records" , 
IF(
Records[Destruction Date]<>BLANK() && YEAR(Records[Destruction Date]) <= YEAR(Today())+1 , 
"Records Expiring In An Year", 
IF(
Records[Retention Begins]<>BLANK() &&  Records[Retention Begins] >= TODAY() , 
"Records on Retention Period", 
"Valid Records"
)))
```

Comment: still, the same thing, giving me three options with the same output.

Comment: I'd do this with "<= TODAY()" on the third part instead of ">="

Comment: @cgrafe makes sense, [OP] you might as well try this